# Separating main screen with different ListView items

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this ListView where it creates a new ListTile item on click of a button (for now it is a floating action button, but it would need to be changed). Here is the code of the ListView:

```
body: Container(
   
      ),

    ),
   
    child: BlocConsumer<FoodBloc, List<Food>>(
      builder: (context, foodList) {
        return ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print("foodList: $foodList");

            Food food = foodList[index];
            
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white60,
              child: ListTile(
                  
                  trailing: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                    
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () => null,
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                  title: Text(food.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                  subtitle: Text(
                   
                    "Calories: ${food.calories}        ${food.price} din\nVegan: ${food.isVegan}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onTap: () => showFoodDialog(context, food, index)),
            );
          },
          itemCount: foodList.length,
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              Divider(color: Colors.black),
        );
      },
      listener: (BuildContext context, foodList) {},
    ),
  ),
```

Here is the floating action button below that creates a new ListTile inside. I would want to have this button functionality besides every type of food like in the image example instead of floating action button (that's not a problem, the layout is):

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    tooltip: 'Add Food',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => FoodForm())),
  ),
```

What I would need to do is have the same functionality, but separate the main screen with different types of food (like in the example image). They would all need to be infinitely tileable (to automatically scroll down depending on how much items there are) and would have icon button besides the type (ie drinks) that would add the ListTile to that Column. Here is a rough example of what I have and what I need.

Here is the 'Submit' button that puts the item on the ListView builder in a ListTile, not sure if anything should be changed there:

```
RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Submit',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        return;
                      }

                      _formKey.currentState.save();

                      Food food = Food(
                        name: _name,
                        calories: _calories,
                        isVegan: _isVegan,
                        //new var
                        price: _price,
                        //added description
                        description: _description,
                      );

                      DatabaseProvider.db.insert(food).then(
                            (storedFood) =>
                                BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context).add(
                              AddFood(storedFood),
                            ),
                          );
```

[image: what I have at the moment]

[image: what i would need]

Comment: First Image is what I currently have, and the second one is what I'd need, so just to separate the types in different categories with same onTap functionality (the button) I have now.

Comment: you are looking for the entire page to be a single scrollable or different sections (drinks, main course...) to be independently scrollable?

Comment: The entire page would be fine, just with separate parts like in the example picture.

Comment: @Joy Terence As mentioned, single scrollable page with all the ListTiles that would go infinitely (depending on the number of items) would work perfectly.